# C++ Console - properly sized still leaves empty space for scroll bars

Tags: c++, windows, console

I am (as many before me, I have done a lot of searcing) trying to have my console display the buffer with no scroll bars. I have the window resized based on the system font size and the requested buffer size, but even after altering (and updating) the Console's style flags, I am still left with empty spaces where the horizontal and vertical scroll bars were.

Can anyone please assist me with this issue?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

const bool adjustWindowSize( const unsigned int p_console_buffer_width, 
const unsigned int p_console_buffer_height )
{
   /// Get the handle to the active window
   HWND l_window_handle( GetConsoleWindow() );
   if( l_window_handle == NULL )
   {
      std::cout << "GetConsoleWindow() failed\n";
      return false;
   }

   /// Get the dimensions of the active window
   RECT l_window_rect;
   if( !GetWindowRect( l_window_handle, &l_window_rect ) )
   {
      std::cout << "GetWindowRect() failed\n";
      return false;
   }

   /// Remove unwanted WindowStyle flags
   LONG l_style( GetWindowLong( l_window_handle, GWL_STYLE ) );
   l_style &= ~( WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | 
                 WS_SIZEBOX );
   SetWindowLong( l_window_handle, GWL_STYLE, l_style );

   /// Set new window size to update the style flags
   if( !SetWindowPos( l_window_handle, HWND_TOP, l_window_rect.left, 
                      l_window_rect.top, l_window_rect.right - 
                      l_window_rect.left, l_window_rect.bottom - 
                      l_window_rect.top, SWP_HIDEWINDOW ) )
   {
      std::cout << "SetWindowPos() failed\n";
      return false;
   }

   /// Get the dimensions of the client area within the window's borders
   RECT l_client_rect;
   if( !GetClientRect( l_window_handle, &l_client_rect ) )
   {
      std::cout << "GetClientRect() failed\n";
      return false;
   }

   /// Get handle to console
   HANDLE l_console_handle( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ) );
   if( l_console_handle == nullptr )
   {
      std::cout << "GetStdHandle() failed\n";
      return false;
   }

   /// Get font information
   CONSOLE_FONT_INFO l_font_info;
   if( !GetCurrentConsoleFont( l_console_handle, false, &l_font_info ) )
   {
      std::cout << "GetCurrentConsoleFont() failed\n";
      return false;
   }

   /// Prepare desired client area size
   unsigned int l_target_width(  l_font_info.dwFontSize.X * 
                                 p_console_buffer_width );
   unsigned int l_target_height( l_font_info.dwFontSize.Y * 
                                 p_console_buffer_height );

   POINT l_top_left;
   l_top_left.x = l_client_rect.left;
   l_top_left.y = l_client_rect.top;
   ClientToScreen( l_window_handle, &l_top_left );

   POINT l_bottom_right;
   l_bottom_right.x = l_client_rect.right;
   l_bottom_right.y = l_client_rect.bottom;
   ClientToScreen( l_window_handle, &l_bottom_right );

   unsigned int l_diff_x = l_window_rect.right - l_bottom_right.x + 
                           l_top_left.x - l_window_rect.left;
   unsigned int l_diff_y = l_window_rect.bottom - l_bottom_right.y + 
                           l_top_left.y - l_window_rect.top;

   /// Adjust window to fit exactly it's borders + the new client size
   l_window_rect.right = l_target_width + l_diff_x;
   l_window_rect.bottom = l_target_height + l_diff_y;

   /// Set new window size
   if( !SetWindowPos( l_window_handle, HWND_TOP, l_window_rect.left, 
                      l_window_rect.top, l_window_rect.right, 
                      l_window_rect.bottom, SWP_SHOWWINDOW ) )
   {
      std::cout << "SetWindowPos() failed\n";
      return false;
   }

   /// Set new console buffer size
   if( !SetConsoleScreenBufferSize( l_console_handle,
                                    COORD( { (SHORT)p_console_buffer_width, 
                                    (SHORT)p_console_buffer_height } ) ) )
   {
      std::cout << "SetConsoleScreenBufferSize() failed\n";
      return false;
   }

   return true;
}

int main()
{
   SetConsoleTitle( (LPCSTR)"Console Test" );

   unsigned int l_buffer_x( 100 );
   unsigned int l_buffer_y( 40 );

   if( !adjustWindowSize( l_buffer_x, l_buffer_y ) )
   {
      std::cout << "adjustWindowSize() failed\n";
      return 1;
   }

   for( unsigned int i( 0 ); i < l_buffer_x * l_buffer_y; ++i )
   {
      std::cout << i % 10;
   }

   SetConsoleCursorPosition( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ),
                             COORD( { 0, 0 } ) );

   return 0;
}
```

[Picture of console with empty spaces where scroll bars were](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpvLc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your question, you want to create console window that has no scroll bars and the visible area is exactly the size of the output screen buffer? This is how you can do this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void SetConsoleWindow(HANDLE conout, SHORT cols, SHORT rows)
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX sbInfoEx;
    sbInfoEx.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(conout, &sbInfoEx);
    sbInfoEx.dwSize.X = cols;
    sbInfoEx.dwSize.Y = rows;
    sbInfoEx.srWindow = { 0, 0, cols, rows };
    sbInfoEx.dwMaximumWindowSize = { cols, rows };
    SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(conout, &sbInfoEx);

    DWORD mode;
    GetConsoleMode(conout, &mode);
    mode &= ~ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT;
    SetConsoleMode(conout, mode);

    SetConsoleTitle(L"Console Test");
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SHORT cols = 100, rows = 20;
    SetConsoleWindow(out, cols, rows);

    for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < cols; ++x)
            std::cout << y %10;

        if (y < rows - 1)
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(out, { 0,0 });

    return 0;
}
```

This needs some explanation. `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX` structure seem to contain all the params needed to make this happen. If you check properties of your console window and compare them with struct members

[image]

you find that `dwSize` corresponds to `Screen Buffer Size`, `srWindow.Right - srWindow.Left` and `srWindow.Bottom - srWindow.Top` correspond to `Window Size`.

If `dwMaximumWindowSize` is not set, it defaults to the boundaries of the desktop and adds scroll bars if window is larger. Setting it as well fixes that.

Lastly, `ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT` needs to be removed from console options to stop cursor jumping to the next line at the end of line, thus scrolling buffer with the last printed character. I have adjusted the print loop to account for that.

Comment: The window size is the 0-based view on the screen buffer, so it should be `cols - 1` and `rows - 1`. That said, `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` is buggy in the actual `srWindow` size that it sets (Windows 7-10; old console, new console), especially when increasing the screen buffer size. It requires an additional two calls to make it behave. Call `GetLargestConsoleWindowSize` and take the minimum of this row and column size and the target screen size. Then set this computed window size via `SetConsoleWindowInfo`.

Comment: Also, `dwMaximumWindowSize`  should be handled as informational, at least with the new console in Windows 10, which doesn't allow resizing the console window larger than the display. You're using the legacy console on an older version of Windows, which unfortunately does allow such an unworkable mess. It should be seen as a bug in the implementation, not a feature.

Comment: @eryksun Appreciate all the points. Do you have a reference to MS documentation describing the above quirks? I don’t think I’ve seen them mentioned in the usual MSDN documents

Comment: The behavior of `SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx` is not documented, and I haven't seen reverse-engineered implementations in Wine or ReactOS. I've seen the suggested workaround using an extra call to `SetConsoleWindowInfo` in various projects and forums, such as in the source code for ConEmu. But most people don't remember to check that the window size will be allowed (either via `GetLargestConsoleWindowSize` or `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx`, `dwMaximumWindowSize`).